# How to use angular 1.5 components with ui-router states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-components, angularjs-1.5

Right now, angular ui-router project didn't have anything explicit about angular 1.5 components.
My project requirement is to use nested states and I want to use angular 1.5 components to easily migrate to angular 2.
I'm looking for a best boilerplate of both.
Options 1,2 & 4 from the below link are supported. I want to know what is the optimal option for nested states and for migration to angular 2.

[Angular 1.5 components with nested states](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/2627)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just shared this solution with a buddy. Not sure if it fits your exact requirements but with UI-Router 1.0.0 you can route directly to a component. To take this a step further, with nested states, we can specify a specific component on a named view. We then link to our child state in the markup using `ui-sref`. When this state becomes active, so does its view's component.

If you want to make these views dynamic, say based on a user role, then you could use a `templateProvider` function. However, with templateProvider you can't use a component to define a view so you may have to just return the component's tag.

e.g. `<editAdminProfileForm></editAdminProfileForm>`

For more on conditional views with templateProvider see my other answer here: [Angularjs ui-router : conditional nested name views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27565838/angularjs-ui-router-conditional-nested-name-views/36746964#36746964)

And here's some additional reading on UI-Router with components:
https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component
https://ui-router.github.io/docs/latest/interfaces/ng1.ng1statedeclaration.html#component

**app.js**

```
...

.state('app', {
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: 'templates/user-profile.html',
})

.state('app.profile', {
  url: '/profile',
  views: {
    'profile': {
      component: 'userProfile'
    }
  }

})

.state('app.profileEdit', {
  views: {
    'editProfile': {
      component: 'editProfileForm'
    }
  }
});
```

**user-profile.html**

```
<ui-view>
  <div ui-view="profile"></div>
  <div ui-view="editProfile"></div>
</ui-view>
```

**user-profile-component.js**
**profile-edit-component.js**

```
yourApp.component('userProfile', { ... });

yourApp.component('editProfileForm', { ... });
```

**user-profile-component.html**

```
<button type="button" ui-sref="app.profileEdit()">Edit Profile</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what exactly I was referring. Finally, ui-router incorportaed this. Thanks for getting it to my notice

Comment: Glad this could help. Note that of this posting, UI-Router 1.0.0 is still in beta. If you're on ~1.0.0 you need to call the component as the template. `template: '<edit-profile-form></edit-profile-form>'`